# GitHub personal access token and Authenticator token

Tags: github, token, authenticator

I recently created a new 'personal access token' as prompted by Github.

They deprecated the use of a password and replaced it with the personal access token on August 13, 2021 when pushing a local repository to a newly created GitHub repository.
I had to create and delete 2 other personal access tokens before my 3rd personal access token was accepted.  And I am no longer prompted to enter username/personal access token now, as an email from GitHub confirmed my new PAT is associated with my GitHub account now.

But I notice in addition to my personal access token which I created in GitHub, I also see in the Authenticator app on my phone a 6 digit token is being generated.  (The personal access token is very long, looks like an SHA)  It is identified as connected to GitHub but GitHub hasn't prompted me to use it nor does GitHub documentation make a reference to its requirement or use.  Can anyone offer some information as to why, and to what end this other token is for?

Answer (score 0):

The 6-digit token you're describing sounds like a two-factor authentication token, which is used to secure your account logins to the github.com website. In contrast, the Personal Access Token is used when interacting with github via a command line interface.

To see the 6-digit code being used in action, try opening a Private/Incognito browser tab and logging into github.com. After entering your username and password, the site should prompt you to enter that 6-digit rotating code as a second factor to secure your account.

See the GitHub documentation for two-factor authentication [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/configuring-two-factor-authentication).

Comment: Thanks, that should have occurred to me.  Same as Google.